# Programa a imprimir caminhos do Windows

Tags: c

Boas , tenho um programa a imprimir caminhos do Windows tipo "C:..".

Eu tenho criadas o seguinte código:

```
    Lista_Viagens cria_lista_viagens(void){
        Lista_Viagens aux;
        aux = (Lista_Viagens) malloc(sizeof (List_nodev));
        if (aux != NULL) {
            aux->viagem=NULL;
            aux->next = NULL;
        }
        return aux;
    }

Lista_Clientes cria_lista_clientes(void){
    Lista_Clientes aux;
    aux =(Lista_Clientes) malloc(sizeof(List_nodec));
    if (aux != NULL) {
        aux->cliente=NULL;
        aux->next = NULL;
    }
    return aux;
}

void insere_cliente(Lista_Clientes lista,Cliente* cliente){
    Lista_Clientes no;
    Lista_Clientes ant;
    no=(Lista_Clientes) malloc(sizeof(List_nodec));
    ant=lista;
    if(no!=NULL){
        while((ant)->next!=NULL){
            ant=ant->next;
        }
        no-> cliente = cliente;
        ant->next=no;
    }

}

void insere_viagem(Lista_Viagens lista,Viagem* viagem){
    Lista_Viagens no;
    Lista_Viagens ant;
    no=(Lista_Viagens) malloc(sizeof(List_nodev));
    ant=lista;
    if(no!=NULL){
        while((ant)->next!=NULL){
            ant=ant->next;
        }
        no->viagem=viagem;
        ant->next=no;
}
    }

void imprime_lista_clientes(Lista_Clientes lista){
    Lista_Clientes l;
    l=lista->next;
    while (l!=NULL){
        printf("Nome: %s CC: %d",l->cliente->nome,l->cliente->cc);
        l=l->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void imprime_lista_viagens(Lista_Viagens lista){
    Lista_Viagens v;
    v=lista->next;
    while (v!=NULL){
        printf("Origem %s Destino: %s  ",v->viagem->origem,v->viagem->destino/*,v->viagem->data.dia,v->viagem->data.mes,v->viagem->data.ano,v->viagem->data.hora,v->viagem->data.minuto*/);
        v=v->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
Cliente* leCliente(){
    Cliente* cliente = (Cliente*) malloc(sizeof(Cliente));
    printf("Insira nome: ");
    scanf("%s", cliente->nome);
    printf("Insira numero do CC: ");
    scanf("%d",&cliente->cc);
    printf("Insira password: ");
    scanf("%s",cliente->password);
    return cliente;

}

Viagem* leViagem(){
    Viagem* viagem=(Viagem*) malloc(sizeof(Viagem));
    //Data* data= (Data*) malloc(sizeof(Data));
    printf("Insira origem: ");
    scanf("%s",viagem->origem);
    printf("Insira Destino: ");
    scanf("%s",viagem->destino);
    printf("Insira numero de passageiros: ");
    scanf("%d",&viagem->n_passageiros);
   /* printf("Insira a data da viagem (dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm)\n");
    scanf("%d", &viagem->data.dia);
    scanf("%d", &viagem->data.mes);
    scanf("%d", &viagem->data.ano);
    scanf("%d", &viagem->data.hora);
    scanf("%d", &viagem->data.minuto);*/
    return viagem;
}
```

E quando corro na main isto:

```
    int main()
{
    Lista_Clientes lclientes=cria_lista_clientes();
    Lista_Viagens lviagens =cria_lista_viagens();
    Viagem* v = (Viagem*)malloc(sizeof(Viagem));
    v=leViagem();
    insere_viagem(lviagens,v);
    imprime_lista_viagens(lviagens);
    return 0;
}
```

Imprime os tais caminhos do windows. Alguém me pode ajudar ? Obrigado

Comment: Qual é seu problema?

Comment: @bigdown, pelo que entendi ao invés de mostrar as estruturas que ele deseja por algum motivo o programa está impriminda uma árvore (ou um) caminho de diretório.

Comment: AP, seria interessante você detalhar melhor o problema, seu programa imprime apenas um caminho? É o caminho para a pasta onde está o executável? é uma árvore  de caminhos? Você tentou debugar o seu programa imprimindo o caminho antes de atribuir leViagem() para v? e antes de insere_viagem()? Caso afirmativo, o resultado é o mesmo? Caso negativo sugiro que o faça e poste o resultado aqui.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal , mas já resolvi.